# Criteria With Inner Constructor

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this DTO

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class TitleTransient implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TitlePrimaryKey primaryKey;

    private EmployeeTitleTransient employeeTitleTransient;

    private LocalDate date;

}
```

And this

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class EmployeeTitleTransient implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate hireDate;

}
```

And this

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class TitlePrimaryKey implements Serializable {

    private String title;
    private Long empNo;
    private LocalDate fromDate;

}
```

I want to know if is possible to make this...

```
@Service
public class TitleService extends IService<Title, Long, TitleRepository> {

    public TitleService(TitleRepository repository, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(repository, entityManager);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Salarie> findAllWithProjectionsWhithoutRelationShip() {

        entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new br.com.jpql.entity.transient_data.title.TitleTransient(new br.com.jpql.entity.model.composite_key.TitlePrimaryKey(t.titlePrimaryKey, t.toDate, t.employee.firstName), new br.com.jpql.entity.transient_data.title.EmployeeTitleTransient(t.employee.lastName, t.employee.hireDate), t.toDate) FROM Titles t");

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Because I am getting this error.

```
2021-06-01 21:15:45.969 ERROR 7546 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new near line 1, column 67 [SELECT new br.com.jpql.entity.transient_data.title.TitleTransient(new br.com.jpql.entity.model.composite_key.TitlePrimaryKey(t.titlePrimaryKey, t.toDate, t.employee.firstName), new br.com.jpql.entity.transient_data.title.EmployeeTitleTransient(t.employee.lastName, t.employee.hireDate), t.toDate) FROM br.com.jpql.entity.model.Title t]] with root cause
```

Stacktrace

```
2021-06-01 21:15:45.969 ERROR 7546 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new near line 1, column 67 [SELECT new br.com.jpql.entity.transient_data.title.TitleTransient(new br.com.jpql.entity.model.composite_key.TitlePrimaryKey(t.titlePrimaryKey, t.toDate, t.employee.firstName), new br.com.jpql.entity.transient_data.title.EmployeeTitleTransient(t.employee.lastName, t.employee.hireDate), t.toDate) FROM br.com.jpql.entity.model.Title t]] with root cause

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new near line 1, column 67 [SELECT new br.com.jpql.entity.transient_data.title.TitleTransient(new br.com.jpql.entity.model.composite_key.TitlePrimaryKey(t.titlePrimaryKey, t.toDate, t.employee.firstName), new br.com.jpql.entity.transient_data.title.EmployeeTitleTransient(t.employee.lastName, t.employee.hireDate), t.toDate) FROM br.com.jpql.entity.model.Title t]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at br.com.jpql.service.TitleService.findAllWithProjectionsWhithoutRelationShip(TitleService.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.com.jpql.service.TitleService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$44346a98.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at br.com.jpql.service.TitleService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5ff7c0.findAllWithProjectionsWhithoutRelationShip(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.com.jpql.controller.TitleController.findAllWithProjectionsWhithoutRelationShip(TitleController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_292]
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

> unexpected token: , near line 1, column 103

it is a `generatedAlias0.titlePrimaryKey` token

It seems like the problem is in the `TitlePrimaryKey` obtainig. It looks like a composite key and, given that no compile time exception have been occured, so it's an existing class, but `Hibernate` generates `titlePrimaryKey` selection as an independent property (whereas it should be the selection of all the key-properties), I believe it may hapenned due to absence of the declaration of this class as a key for the `Title` entity. Did you use `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId`+`@Embeddable` annotations to mark this class as a composite key? If not, follow [this article](https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-composite-primary-key) with nice examples.

Comment: well, I've reproduced the issue and got the same exception, but the different stacktrace, which nonetheless, is about parsing of the clause within the `Hibernate` lib. So, it seems like such a syntax doesn't supported by `Hibernate`